# Python print(int) gives me <type 'int'> instead of <builtin function 'int'>

Tags: python

Does that mean when I call int("123"), it is actually creating an instance of int class?

Comment: Thanks for user2357112's answer, a follow up question would be: when I create write a = int(123) and b = int(123), then do id(a) and id(b), they return the same result. Does that mean every time when you create an new instance of a builtin type, Python looks for existing instance and point it there?

Comment: For those who downvoted the question, please tell me if there is something I am not doing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much. It's not necessarily creating a new instance of the class, since for numbers in a certain range, Python will store canonical instances of those integers and hand you an old one when you ask for a new one. You can do the same thing with your own classes if you want, by implementing `__new__`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But when I create write `a = int(123)` and `b = int(123)`, then do `id(a)` and `id(b)`, they return the same result. Does that mean every time when you create an new instance of a builtin type, Python looks for existing instance and point it there?

Comment: @MichaelLee: `int` saves canonical instances for numbers in a certain range, something like -5 to 255. When you ask for a "new" instance from that range, `int` hands you an old one.